# Drop multiple columns based on a condition

Tags: r

I want to ensure that the column has at least 2 observations greater than 0. How to delete multiple columns that has only one observation greater >0;

```
Date     | Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4
10/10/12 | 1     | 1     | 1     | 0
10/11/12 | 0     | 5     | 2     | 2
10/12/12 | 0     | 3     | 0     | 0
10/13/12 | 0     | 2     | 0     | 0
10/14/12 | 0     | 2     | 0     | 0
```

The `Item1` column should be removed from the data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `colSums` and keep column which has at least 2 values greater than 0. We use [-1] here to ignore `Date` column and check the greater than 0 condition for remaining columns.

```
cbind(df[1], df[-1][colSums(df[-1] > 0) >= 2])

#      Date  Item2 Item3
#1 10/10/12      1     1
#2 10/11/12      5     2
#3 10/12/12      3     0
#4 10/13/12      2     0
#5 10/14/12      2     0
```

`Item1` and `Item4` columns are removed since both of them have only one observation greater than 0.

---

Another option is `select_if` from `dplyr` using the same logic

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(df[1], df[-1] %>% select_if(funs(sum(. > 0) >= 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks, What if I wanna do that on the last three rows only ?

Comment: I used tail function and it worked. Thanks Ronak   cbind(df[1], df[-1][colSums(tail(df[-1],n=24) > 0) >= 2])

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option.  We can use `apply` to get the non zero count for each column in the data frame.  Then, we can subset the data frame under the condition that only columns with more than one non zero value are retained.

```
counts <- sapply(df, function(x) {
    sum(x > 0)
})

df[, counts > 1]
```